# MongoDb delete by parametr

Tags: php, mongodb

I try NoSQL.
I know how delete by id

```
$criteria = array(
  '_id' => new MongoId('5277aeb6b28fada80a00002b'),
    );
 $users->remove($criteria);
```

but how to delete if you new for example value, like "name"="John"

Comment: `$criteria = array('name'=>'john');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do absolutely the same thing as you have done with `_id` field:

```
$users->remove(array(
  'name' => 'John'
));
```

You can always look at [mongodb php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php#refsect1-mongocollection.remove-examples) to find how to transform mongodb shell code to php.

Comment: It's working with normal data, but it's not works on such situation                                                              "token": "lxsTWrX2nJhrC8ysPY5V\/fuwPAnA\/TwMRhg7IcdVNYU="

Answer (score 0):

I don't now how it is represented in PHP, but in Scala you would do something like this:

```
val criteria = MongoDBObject("name" -> "John")
coll.remove(criteria)
```